# Prove that V/C is a partition of V

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

If C is a subspace of a vector space V and x V , the set
x + C ={ $ x + c : c ∈ C $ }
is called a coset of C. The set of all cosets is denoted V/C.

I need to prove that the set of all cosets ( V/C ) is a partition of the vector space V.

Any help or intuition is appreciated, I don't know where to start.
Thanks

Comment: let $v\in V$ then $v$ is an element in $v+C$, what is left to prove now is that if $v+C$ and $v'+C$ intersect then they're equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Define
$$x\sim y \iff x-y\in C$$
and prove that it is a equivalence relation. What are the equivalent classes of such relation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to show:

1. $V= \bigcup_{x \in V}(x+C)$

and

2. for $x,y \in V$ we have $x+C=y+C$ or $(x+C) \cap (y+C)= \emptyset$

Hint for 2. : if $x,y \in V$, then we have two cases: (i) $x-y \in C$ or (ii) $x-y \notin C$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The fibers (preimages of singletons) of *any* surjective function form a partition of its domain.

What are the fibers of the function $\nu:V\to V/C$ prescribed by $x\mapsto x+C$?